# Logarithms and complex derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$,$g$ be continuous in a domain $\Omega$ (open and connected, subset of
> $\mathbb{C}$). Suppose that $g(z) \not = 0$ for all $z \in \Omega$. What relationship exists between $f$ and $g$ if $(f(z))^m = (g(z))^m$, $z\in \Omega$, where $m \not = 0$ is an integer? use this
> to show that if $\Omega = (\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R})\cup(-a,a)$, and $(j(z))^2 = a^2-z^2$, $a > 0$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and
> $(i(z))^2 = a^2-z^2$, so $i(z) = -j(z)$ or $i(z) = j(z)$.

For the first, I did the following:
$$
(f(z))^m = (g(z))^m \Rightarrow e^{mLog(f(z))} = e^{mLog(g(z))} \Rightarrow mLog(f(z)) = mLog(g(z))+2\pi k i, k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

and so,
$$
\left | \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} \right | = 1, |g(z)| \not = 0
$$

but I don't know if I did it right nor do I know how to get to the second thing that they ask me using the result that I found.

Answer (score 1):

$(\frac {f(z)} {g(z)})^{m}=1$. There aer only finitely many complex numbers $\zeta$ such that $\zeta^{m}=1$. Hence $\frac f g$ takes only finitely many values. Since it is also continuous (its image has to be connected and so) it has to be a constant. So $f=cg$ where $c$ is a constant with  $c^{m}=1$.